# OpenLayers map breaks at certain zoom level when many popups exist in the map

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, popup

I'm still learning OpenLayers. I found this weird issue in my OpenLayers map. I create FramedCloud popups and add them to each features.

```
popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("popup",
    OpenLayers.LonLat.fromString(parsedFeature.geometry.toShortString()),
    null,
    "<div style='font-size:.8em'>date: " + someDate + "<br>longitude: " + data.lon + "<br>latitude: " + data.lat + "</div>",
    null,
    false
);
```

But I don't add them until it gets to certain zoom level. Then I add the popups to the map with the following code

```
olMap.events.register('zoomend', olMap, function () {
    var zoom = olMap.getZoom();
    var popup;
    if (zoom > 11) {
        for (i = 0; i < dm.currentLocationsVector.features.length; i++) {
            popup = dm.currentLocationsVector.features[i].popup;
            if (!popup.map) {
                olMap.addPopup(popup);
            }
        }
    } else if (zoom < 12) {
        for (i = 0; i < vector.features.length; i++) {
            popup = vector.features[i].popup;
            if (popup.map) {
                olMap.removePopup(popup);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Actually it works good until zoom 17 then when the map zoom level gets 18 the map breaks.

[image]

It looks like the popups and the map get messed in some way.
I don't think I have problem in creating popups.Thought it might some bug in OpenLayers.

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example, maybe on jsfiddle?

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe Thanks for your interest, I'll do so as soon as I can.